# htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I use htaccess to rewrite my URL's so here is what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So if I go to **domain.com/services** then it works perfect, but what I want to do is make it so if they do type in **domain.com/services.php** then it will work instead of not being found.

Also.. if I go to domain.com/services/ (with a trailing slash) then it acts like it's not found.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have limited "rewrite loop" (limited to 2 iterations only). Use these rules:

```
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)(\.php)?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

If you do not like it, here is an alternative (but I still prefer #1, but maybe this one will be better for your setup/app logic -- this assumes that `index.php` is located in website root folder):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)(\.php)?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.php$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

add slash as aceptable possible character (note ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`\/`$)

Comment: The error went away but just like the other answer, for some reason it is showing every page as the index.

Answer (score 0):

For the second requirement (the php extension) try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(\.php)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

untested, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) index.php?page=$1 [L]

You aren't allowing a period, so the '.php' fails the expression since it is terminated with $

Comment: Thanks but this takes all of my styling away and messes up the site.  I'm not sure why every solution is not working for me :(

Comment: What should the expected URL look like? ... index.php?page=services