# redirect issue with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem in my htaccess rules.

Here my htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=permanent]

RewriteRule ^create$ create.php [L]
RewriteRule ^delete$ delete.php [L]
RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ fetch.php?fetch=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/make$ fetch.php?fetch=$1&make=do [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/made$ fetch.php?fetch=$1&made=done [QSA,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Each time i go to my website directory (http://localhost/myscript) i got redirected many time and receive a message: Page not redirect properly.

When i remove this lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ fetch.php?fetch=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/make$ fetch.php?fetch=$1&make=do [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\$\.A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/made$ fetch.php?fetch=$1&made=done [QSA,L]
```

I got it work ... but this three lines are importants for my script.

Help to figure it out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone interested on this.
I added this conditions to my code and resolved the problem.

```
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
```

Got response from here: [htaccess Rewrite Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851549/htaccess-rewrite-rule/6852089#6852089)